Editing Exclusive Boolean Field in Flask-Admin Views
I have a Flask-Admin view where I want a boolean field (is_first) to behave exclusively, meaning only one entry can be set as True while others are False. To achieve this, I've converted it into a radio button format within the view UI, as shown in the image below:

Here's the relevant code snippet:
def format_is_first(view, context, model, name):
    checked = 'checked' if model.get('is_first') else ''
    step_id = str(model.get('_id'))
    radio_button = f'<input type="radio" name="is_first" data-step-id="{step_id}" {checked}>'
    return Markup(radio_button)

class StepView(ModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'is_first')
    form = StepForm
    column_formatters = {
        'is_first': format_is_first
    }

My questions are:

Am I on the right track with this approach? If so, how can I ensure that changes made via the radio buttons in the View UI are reflected in the database? I suppose that there are some hooks Flask Admin provide, but I failed to find any.

If this approach is not ideal due to violations of the MVC paradigm or other concerns, what is the recommended best practice in Flask-Admin for implementing exclusive boolean field behavior? I believe this behavior is fundamental and may have broader applicability.


